# Save the records in text register persistently

Tags: registers

I utilize the text register to collect new words I encountered

`C-x  r s w` (w for word)

append others to it with `M-x append-to-register`

Record all the word collected to a `works.org` file at the end of the day.

Unfortunately, If the  machine crashed during the day, all the records in register are gone.

How could save the records in text register persistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use registers for that, you could just write to words.org during the day. Something like this will do that either for the region you have highlighted, or the word at point, and you could bind it to a key if you want.

```
(require 'thingatpt)

(defun my-append-word ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((word (if (not (region-active-p))
          (word-at-point)
        (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))))
    (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "words.org")
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert word "\n")
      (save-buffer))))
```